# Pivot Table Range excluding column in middle

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

How to exclude particular columns from Pivot Table Range. The goal is to run macro that set Condition Formatting ( 3 colour scale)  but it will skip selected columns. For example Pivot Table has L:BR and columns N+S+X have to be excluded.
How it can be achieved ?

code for formatting only below:

```
Sub CONDIT3COLOR2()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

pt.TableRange1.Select
    
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueNumber
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Value = 0
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 230
        
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValueNumber
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 1500
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = 155
        
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueNumber
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Value = 5000
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the cross range with `Intersect`.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim rngPvt As Range
    Set pvt = Sheet1.PivotTables(1)
    Set rngPvt = Application.Intersect(pvt.TableRange1, Sheet1.Range("L:M,O:R,T:W,Y:BR"))
    With rngPvt
        ' Set FormatConditions
    End With
End Sub
```

Please ref to the following page for syntax.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I just needed add rngPvt.select and it is working now
 Sub demo()
  [...]    
rngPvt.Select
      
    With rngPvt
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
   [...]
    End Sub

Is there a different way to do that? I mean without .select ?

Comment: You don't have to `select` a range before setting conditional format. `rngPvt.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3`